# Critique my roadmap to learn computer networking?

Tags: networks, curriculum-review

**Purpose:**

For Linux System Administrator. I don't need CCNA cert. I don't need to be explicitly a network engineer. I just need to be able to troubleshoot network related issues.

**Already Tried**

Googling and learning. Didn't work. I need to have a good grasp of concepts taught in college at first! No next question. Thankfully not my first time learning the college textbook on Networks.

**Roadmap**

Step 1)
I don't like tanenbaum, so these are the books that I'll buy and read.

- Fourouzan networks
- Stallings networks
- TCP IP by philip miller book
- Comptia network+/A+ good book
- CCNA official cert guide book

Step 2)

- Networking for Systems Administrators (It Mastery)
  Michael W Lucas
- TCP/IP Network Administration oreilly
- The Practice of System and Network Administration oreilly

Step 3)

- DNS and BIND oreilly
- Wireshark course
- HTTP the definitive guide, oreilly

Critique this roadmap and add your valuable input here. If you've any books suggestions on the way, do share! If I could get apprenticeship/internship in networks, it'd be great, but I don't have one atm and I'm working as a linuxadmin. This whole would take me about 1.5 years to complete along with my job. Thus I want to know that if learning all these would be well worth it? Tell me if I can cut out some garbage here.

Answer (score 0):

what level are you starting from? because if you want to mainly deal with network issues, then it's best to know what are you doing instead of how to do it. it seems to me that if you don't know anything about networks then starting with something like Fourouzan networks, which (if i'm not wrong) teaches you how to create and handle networks might be less useful for what you're seeking. this isn't a book, but my (and also most people i know that deal with networks) #1 suggestion is [networking fundamentals](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIFyRwBY_4bRLmKfP1KnZA6rZbRHtxmXi&si=sK-6m4yPSIrtN1qS), which is a youtube course that teaches you the fundamentals of networks. even if you have a little bit of knowledge around how the internet works, i would still recommend this course, since it helps in refreshing your memory and making sure you know every layer properly.